How to handle elements adding/removing in structure of arrays
I want to make safe and easy adding and removing elements from structure of arrays. Is there a way in modern C++ to do so without writing functions and make these operations explicitly on every array? Separate functions do their work, but with increasing number of arrays code duplication (long list of arrays) becomes more visible and error-prone.
Something like (which, of course, doesn't compile demo; I don't provide error log, since this is just code to show the idea, not code which should work as is)
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> value;
    std::vector<float> threshold;

    auto SoA = std::views::zip(value, threshold);

    std::fill_n(std::inserter(SoA, SoA.begin()), 1, { 0.0f, 0.0f } );

    std::erase(SoA.end());
}

would work for me.
Here I mean that I want to zip somehow vectors in one place and in many other places just use one safe call to change them. Real importance of this will be noticeable when there are many vectors which build the structure and many places where you need add/remove elements.
Useful sources
I found two related implementations:

Structure of Arrays
vapid soa

They are comprehensive and well-developed, but the question still on the table if this is possible to implement easier (taking into account my simpler requirements).

filling each vector separately is more cache friendly

@MarekR, of course, but "premature optimization is the root of all evil". In many places code simplicity, transparency and avoiding code duplication is more important than performance of a tiny rarely executed piece of code. Again, I don't mind if the approach will unroll to sequential calls to underlying vectors. And, very often I need to add/remove only one element.

A std::list or vector taking address of each element in zip view? I don't get the use case. A struct holding reference of each element doesn't work?

Tuple of references to vectors with a vector-like interface wouldn't do? Devil's in the details when it comes to how this should behave and there might be some amount of boilerplate to it, but it seems definitely possible. EDIT: though the number of variadic templates might be putting the reader off ;)

@LouisGo, can you, please, show in demo what do you mean? What kind of additional information you'd like me to add to the question to cover the use case?

@alagner, I just want to make a single call to add (or remove) an element to all these vectors. As simple as it would be in case of AoS (array of structures). I just need a simple solution which will protect me from addressing many vectors in each such a place and avoid missing some of them, especially, when new ones added. Can you please show you proposal in the demo? Again, if it is simple enough or if the complexity could be encapsulated.

Far from complete, but just to demonstrate how it could work. Main question is if the amount of boilerplate is acceptable to you, because it's going to be significant.

@alagner, thank you so much for your time and help here. Meanwhile I found a couple of open-source implementations related to the topic (Structure of Arrays and
vapid soa). Am I correct that your approach is closer to the latter? I am fine with any abstractable approach (with code which could be hidden, like in your case), but looking for a solution without "nameless" parts in API like std::get<0>(zel). Still curious why such a simple task requires such complex things to implement. Thank you again!
